# Difference between Qt Creator and Ubuntu SDK?

Tags: application-development, qt, ubuntu-sdk, qt-creator

Having downloaded them both when I installed the Ubuntu SDK, I wonder if there is any tangible difference between the two, such as the libraries being employed.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### Qt Creator

Qt Creator is a cross-platform IDE (integrated development environment) tailored to the needs of Qt developers. It is part of the Qt Project [qt-project.org](http://www.qt-project.org/) .

Qt Creator focuses on providing features that help new Qt users get up and running faster, and also boost the productivity of experienced Qt developers.

- Code editor with C++, QML and ECMAscript support
- Rapid code navigation tools
- Syntax highlighting and code completion
- Static code checking and style hints as you type
- Support for source code refactoring
- Context sensitive help
- Code folding
- Parenthesis matching and parenthesis selection modes

### Ubuntu SDK

The Ubuntu SDK is your full-featured integrated development environment (IDE) for writing Ubuntu apps.

Based on **Qt Creator**, the Ubuntu SDK provides all the tools you need to get up and running and super productive developing Ubuntu apps of all types, with QML and HTML5 supported now and other possibilities on the radar.

More importantly the Ubuntu SDK comes with a huge collections of QML components to create Touch applications themed for Ubuntu, visit this [link](http://developer.ubuntu.com/api/qml/sdk-1.0/Ubuntu.Components/) for a quick overview.

Ubuntu SDK highlights:

- All the technical brilliance and capabilities of the QtCreator
  platform with additional Ubuntu-specific features layered on top
- New Project Wizard simplifies creating new QML and HTML5 app projects
- Bazaar (and other) version control system built-in
- Beautiful GUI with wide range of advanced code editing features and
  preferences
- Run app projects from the SDK on the development system, on attached
  devices, and on Ubuntu emulators
- Manage attached physical devices and create and manage Ubuntu
  emulator instances
- Package the app project as a click package for easy publishing
- Install and run click packages on devices and Ubuntu emulators
- Debug support
- Run kits for run time environment and other options

Sources:

- https://qt-project.org/wiki/Category:Tools::QtCreator
- http://developer.ubuntu.com/apps/sdk/

Answer (score 3):

Qt Creator is a powerful, advanced and versatile IDE (integrated development environment) combining under a singular roof advanced code editor for C++ and QML, etc, code completion, syntax highlighting, code checking, etc, essentially, presenting itself as a solid developer-friendly tool.

Qt Creator has been adopted by Ubuntu as the main app-creation tool, allowing developers to create beautiful and full-of-features software.

Qt Creator has just landed in Ubuntu 13.10 (via Ubuntu Software Center), bringing a significant number of new features, changes and optimizations.

**Qt Creator has been renamed to Ubuntu SDK**, new name aligning the handy IDE to its new Ubuntu identity, namely, being the development ground for the next generation of Ubuntu applications, as well as being more accurately and intuitively presented to developers, developers now hassle-free able to identify the needed tool for developing Ubuntu applications.<sup>[ILU](http://iloveubuntu.net/qt-creator-271-renamed-ubuntu-sdk-available-ubuntu-1310-numerous-new-features)</sup>